# Umbraco Razor - iterate through multi node picker

Tags: razor, umbraco, loops

I'm trying to iterate through the muti node picker with razor. My alias for my widget is "venuesPicker." I'm getting the error, "cannot load macro file." Here's what I have so far:

```
<umbraco:Macro runat="server" language="cshtml">
@{
    using uComponents.Core;
    using uComponents.Core.uQueryExtensions;

    foreach (var x in Model.venuesPicker)
    {
        @x.highlightTitle
    }
}
</umbraco:Macro>
```

Answer (score 7):

Check out my answer to this [our.umbraco.org forum post](http://our.umbraco.org/forum/developers/razor/33050-IngroupsOf?p=0#comment121481). Basically, depending on whether the MNTP is using XML or CSV, you can do one of the following:

**CSV:**

```
@using umbraco.MacroEngines
@inherits DynamicNodeContext
@if (Model.HasValue("venuesPicker"))
{
    string[] ids = Model.venuesPicker.Split(',');

    <ul>
    @foreach (string id in ids)
    {
        var node = Library.NodeById(id);
        if (node.Id != 0)
        {
            // If node exists:
            <li><a href="@node.Url">@node.Name</a></li>
        }
    }
    </ul>
}
```

**XML:**

```
@using umbraco.MacroEngines
@inherits DynamicNodeContext
@if (Model.HasValue("venuesPicker"))
{
    <ul>
    @foreach (var item in Model.venuesPicker)
    {
        var node = Library.NodeById(item.InnerText);
        if (node.Id != 0)
        {
            // If node exists:
            <li><a href="@node.Url">@node.Name</a></li>
        }
    }
    </ul>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use uQuery.getNodesByCSV or uQuery.getMediaByCSV too.
uQuery was added to Umbraco core in 4.9 I think, otherwise you can install uComponents package

so for example I have something like this in 4.9.1 to loop through some media

```
@using umbraco.MacroEngines
@using umbraco.cms.businesslogic.media
@inherits umbraco.MacroEngines.DynamicNodeContext
@{
    <div class="slideshow">
        @foreach (Media img in uQuery.GetMediaByCsv(Model.lightBoxImages))
        {
            <figure>
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="@img.GetImageUrl()"  />
                </a>
            </figure>   
        }
    </div>
}
```

[further info on Umbraco forum](http://our.umbraco.org/forum/developers/razor/33302-Iterating-through-ultimate-picker)